# Android EditText pushing view down

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following view:

[image]

And every time I edit the search EditText (even when there is no text change, just focusing), my View does this:

[image]

My XML code is this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
tools:context="garbi.mx.garbi.Home">

<!-- The main content view -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
            android:id="@+id/mapFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/geolocation"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:onClick="centerMap"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/marker"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />


        </FrameLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="¿Dónde se encuentra tu coche?"
        android:textColor="#43B9BD"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />


    <!--<EditText
        android:id="@+id/places_autocomplete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />-->

    <com.seatgeek.placesautocomplete.PlacesAutocompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/places_autocomplete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        app:pacv_googleMapsApiKey="AIzaSyBjn1_8gclbpsRvfO6ndKQKEuCLUaARw5s"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/search"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/places_autocomplete" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton">

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/field_small"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:onClick="setCar"
            android:id="@+id/carButton"
            android:text="Agregar \nVehículo"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/field_small"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:onClick="setPayment"
            android:id="@+id/paymentButton"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:text="Agregar \nMétodo de pago"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Solicitar Garbi"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/large_button"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:onClick="request"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <!-- Profile Box -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:onClick="editProfile"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rain"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Isabel Tapia Reyes"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Experimenting with it has lead me to think this has to do with the length of the texts inside the buttons (they are dynamic). If the button has more than one line, it is going to get pushed down. One line does ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow any of the two options:

1.**Add** `android:baselineAligned="false"` to your `LinearLayout` containing the buttons

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
```

2.**Use** `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for the child element to grow it's view equally when the text changes

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/carButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="setCar"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Agregar \nVehículTestTestTestTestTest"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/paymentButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="setPayment"
            android:text="Agregar \nMétodo de pago"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried the first answer and it worked! Thank you so much. Going to read a little more about what baseAligned does